# New to threading in C#, can you make thread methods generic and what are the dangers?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm just now starting to get into the idea of threading, and wanted to know if I could make this more abstract. Both foo and bar derive methods from a base class, so I'd like to pass in one or the other and be able to do work using a method that was derived. I'd also like to know how you properly name threads and the methods inside threads.

```
    if (ChkFoo.Checked)
            {
                Thread fooThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.ThreadedFooMethod));
                fooThread.Start();
            }
    if (ChkBar.Checked)
            {
                Thread barThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.ThreadedBarMethod));
                barThread.Start();
            }
    .
    .
    .
    public void ThreadedFooMethod()
    {
    Foo newFoo = new Foo();
    //Do work on newFoo
    }

    public void ThreadedBarMethod()
    {
    Bar newBar = new Bar();
    //Do similar work
    }
```

Thanks all!

Comment: with .net2.0 and anonymous delegates and all that jazz, you are no longer required to explicitly create delegate instances, so `Thread fooThread = new Thread (new ThreadStart (this.ThreadedFooMethod));` may also be written more concisely as `Thread fooThread = new Thread (ThreadedFooMethod);` . whether it improves or degrades legibility is up to you, just a "more you know" moment :)

Comment: Thanks! The place I am interning at is still using .net 2.0, and they're slowly putting a plan in place to adapt 4.0. That said, I went off of a tutorial and used the "this" keyword - but that's great! Anything I can do to trim code without harming performance or legibility is useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would look at using an interface that they both implement.  And if you really care if its a foo or bar you can use the "is" keyword and "as".  You can pass in stuff to a thread using the thread pool but it must be of type object.

ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new WaitCallback("FuncName"), new "Foo or Bar");

Comment: I did not think of that. I think that's what I'll go with.